# How do I make android keyboard display a '.com' button

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an `EditText`.  My `imeOptions` attribute for the `EditText` is `actionGo`.  What do I have to do to make it display a '.com' key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by [android:inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) i think.
Try `textUri`.

Comment: that didn't do it.  That just gave me the standard keyboard

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to provide your edittext with input type attribute to do this.

```
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

Comment: this gave me the @ key but not the .com key

Comment: this might be because of the different os versions.

Answer (score 1):

Using the EditText attribute `android:inputType="textWebEditText"` should give you the .com and applicable web buttons